# Highcharts "click" range on load with jquery, or addSeries on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I"m using afterSetExtremes event to retrieve min and max x and y coordinates. Then, I add this series upon range selection. The problem is the series is not shown upon load. The simplest solution would be to simulate a range select on chart load. Is this possible? If not, is it possible to add this same series upon load?

```
xAxis: {
        events: {
  afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
    var points = e.target.series[0].points,
            minPoint = points[1],
        maxPoint = points[points.length - 1]

    if(minPoint.y < maxPoint.y)
    {
    var series_color = 'green';
    }
    else{
    series_color = 'red';
    }
    chart.addSeries({       
    data:[{x:minPoint.x,y:minPoint.y},{x:maxPoint.x,y:maxPoint.y}],
    color: series_color,
    dashStyle: 'shortdot',
    id: 'trend'
});
while(chart.series.length > 3)
{
chart.get('trend').remove();
}
  }

}
    }
```

See jsfiddle to see how it's currently working: http://jsfiddle.net/kd3aLp6m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `load` event you can use `fireEvent` method to trigger the `afterSetExtremes` event. Also, to increase performance, you can set the `redraw` parameter in `addSeries` metohd to `false` in all calls except the first one.

```
    chart: {
        ...,
        events: {
            load: function() {
                Highcharts.fireEvent(
                    this.xAxis[0],
                    'afterSetExtremes', {
                        redraw: true
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    },
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bdnho9uc/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.fireEvent

Comment: Thank you. I tried expanding by calculating the linear regression but am now receiving the error "Chart is undefined." Everything works up until I add the load: function(). Something seems to be raising an error within the fireEvent. Here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yk7t65j4/

Comment: Hi @notevenbuttery, You can not use the external `chart` variable: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hf4x9z7o/